# Counting the functions with f(i) ≤ f(i+1) for all i=1,..,n-1

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How can I determine how many functions are weakly monotone increasing from $[n]\equiv \{1,..,n\}$ to itself:

$$  f:[n] \to [n] \text{ so that } f(i) \leq f(i+1) \; \forall i\in[n-1]$$

Thank you for any help.

Comment: By "number of the function" do you mean how does one count how many functions have this property?

Comment: How many increasing sequences can you form from $1,...,n$?

Comment: @hardmath yes this is what i mean

Comment: Here is one way to think about it: You have $n$ 'N's and $n-1$ '+'s, and a collection of $2n-1$ 'places'. You have so place the '+'s (or 'N's, if you wish) in any of these places. The '+' represents a 'plus 1', so if $n=3$ and you have $N++NN$, then this represents the sequence $1,3,3$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that altogether, the function takes $k$ different values; there are $\binom{n}{k}$ choices for these values. Call an index $i$ a *switch position* if $f(i) \neq f(i+1)$. There are $k-1$ such switch positions out of $n-1$ possibilities, resulting in $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ choices. Altogether, we get
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k} \binom{n-1}{k-1} = \binom{2n-1}{n}.
$$

Another way to obtain this formula is to consider a code for generating a monotone function. The code consists of two instructions: I (increment) and D (display). To execute the code, we initialize a counter at the value 1. For each I instruction, we increment the counter. For each D instruction, we add a value to the function. We require that the counter end up at $n$. Each code contains $n-1$ I instructions and $n$ D instructions, and so there are $\binom{2n-1}{n}$ possible codes.

Comment: do you mean f(i) $\leq$ f(i+1) ?

Comment: I had better, if you want $f(i) < f(i+1)$ then only the identity function $f(i) = i$ works.